# Node-red custom node, How to use the node property?

Tags: node-red

I am trying to create custom node, I am experimenting with very simple one. I need to use the node's property, the value chosen by the user from a dropdown, to send/output the value of that property with msg.payload.

This is the error msg in the debug tab:

```
4/7/2017 21.45.06node: lolo
msg : error
"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
```

This is the desired output:

*"ppp[lolo:m2]"*

I remove the line with $ in js file, because it does not recognize jQuery. I use this instead

```
msg.payload = msg.payload +"[" + nodeName+":"+ node.axis +"]";
```

but in output the option value is undefined instead of value of one of the options from select dropdown:

```
5/7/2017 11.34.22node: 5aa4aa59.f9fa04
msg.payload : string[19]
"ppp[lolo:undefined]"
```

This is the html file for the node:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('Hello World',{
        category: 'Demo',
        color: '#ffaaaa',
        defaults: {
            name: {value:""},
  axis:{value:""}
        },
        inputs:1,
        outputs:1,
        icon: "face.png",
        label: function() {
            return this.name||"Hello World";
        }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="Hello World">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-name"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="node-input-name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-topic"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Topic</label>
        <input type="text" id="node-input-topic" placeholder="Topic">
    </div>
 <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-axis"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Motor</label>
        <!--<input type="text" id="node-input-axis" placeholder="axis">-->
  <select value="" id="node-input-axis" placeholder="axis">
            <option value="m1">m1</option>
            <option value="m2">m2</option>
            <option value="m3">m3</option>
            <option value="m4">m4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-red" data-help-name="Hello World">
    <p>A node that increments every time a new message is received and sends Hello World in return.<br/>
    </p>
</script>
```

This is the js file for the node:

```js
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function helloWorld(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
        //var context = this.context();
  var nodeName = this.name;
  var axis = config.axis; 
        var node = this;
  //var $ = require('jQuery');
  var x = $("#node-input-axis").val();
        this.on('input', function(msg) {
   msg.payload = msg.payload +"[" + nodeName+":"+ x +"]";
   //{payload: nodeName+" "+node.axis};
   node.send(msg);
        });
  //console.log(value);
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("Hello World",helloWorld);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to remember that the 2 separate parts of a Node-RED node run in very different locations:

- The `.js` file runs on the backend server side of Node-RED
- The `.html` file runs in the web browser that is accessing the Node-RED Editor on the users client machine.

This means that the `.js` file has no direct access to the fields in the editor configuration window and also there is no access to jquery (`$`) notation.

When a flow is deployed all the configuration variables are passed to the backend in the `config` variable. You have already accessed that value in:

```
var axis = config.axis;
```

so rather than the `var x = $("#node-input-axis").val();` you can just use the `axis` variable.

You can't use `node.axis` because you have not bound `config.axis` to either `this.axis` or `node.axis` before trying to use it

e.g.:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function helloWorld(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
        //var context = this.context();
        var nodeName = this.name;
        this.axis = config.axis; 
        var node = this;

        this.on('input', function(msg) {
            msg.payload = msg.payload +"[" + nodeName+":"+ node.axis +"]";
            //{payload: nodeName+" "+ node.axis};
            node.send(msg);
        });
        //console.log(value);
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("Hello World",helloWorld);
};
```